# ¿Es posible realizar entrada de datos de multiples líneas por teclado?

Tags: cmd, batch

Estoy trabajando en un archivo `.bat` que precisa de una entrada de datos por teclado, el caso es que quisiera saber si existe la posibilidad de que dicha entrada sea una sucesion de lineas con espacios y retornos de carro, ya que de forma directa, usando `"set /p VARIABLE= ..."` el primer retorno de carro lo interpreta como el fin de la entrada de datos.

Un ejemplo de entrada de datos seria la siguiente:

```
FIRST value is 738
SECOND value is 721
THIRD value is 932
```

Al intentar copiar esto directamente en la consola, la entrada se queda unicamente en la primera línea "`FIRST value is 738"`.

El objetivo final es poder asignar cada una de las líneas a un array para poder trabajar con dichos datos, creo que esto es posible de hacer leyendo los datos desde un fichero, aunque no he investigado la manera, pero lo que de verdad me interesaria seria poder hacerlo introduciendo dichos datos directamente en la consola (haciendo copiar y pegar).

Saludos.

EDIT-------------------------------------------------

Edito para poner de forma más clara lo dicho en el último comentario:

```
set i=1
set list[0]=primero
set list[1]=segundo
IF %list[%i%]%==segundo (echo coincide) ELSE (echo NO coincide)

  >NO coincide

IF %list[i]%==segundo (echo coincide) ELSE (echo NO coincide)

  >NO coincide

IF %list[!i!]%==segundo (echo coincide) ELSE (echo NO coincide)  

  >No se esperaba value en este momento

IF %list[1]%==segundo (echo coincide) ELSE (echo NO coincide)   

  >coincide
```

Como se puede apreciar en el ultimo ejemplo, al poner el indice directamente en el array, la condicion funciona correctamente, pero no encuentro la forma de usar una variable como indice para el array, la solucion que me dijiste '[!i!]' parece realmente hacer algo, pero me dice eso de "No se esperaba value en este momento"

Comment: ¿Cómo sabrías cuándo parar de leer de teclado?

Comment: mmm es una buena pregunta, ¿quizas al encontrar la combinacion de retorno de carro y espacio en blanco justo a continuación? Quizas es un imposible, disculpen mi ignorancia, soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Lo que estoy pensando es que podrías leer varias veces seguidas, en un bucle, entradas de teclado hasta que encuentres algo como "end" o similar

Comment: El problema es que la entrada de teclado no reconoce nunca más que la primera línea, es decir, deja de leer automaticamente en el primer retorno de carro, por lo que, no puede asignar toda esa cadena de texto a una sola variable,¿se puede ignorar de alguna forma ese retorno de carro como fin de entrada y asignar una cadena concreta como sugieres?

Answer (score 1):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente:

Primero, simular un bucle *while* en batch, ya que no existen:

```
:while
 <cosas a realizar>

IF <condicion> goto while
```

Usando ese bucle, puedes leer repetidas veces del teclado,hasta que escribas algo como "fin":

```
set i=0
:while
set /A i+=1
set /P list[%i%]=">"
if NOT !list[%i%]! == "fin" goto while
```

No uso windows, así que no he podido probar el código, pero creo que te puedes hacer una idea

EDIT: Me confundí con los `%` y los `!`, prueba ahora.

Comment: Tu idea parece muy buena pero me he topado con otro problema, el "IF" de la solucion que propones no funciona, he estado probando y no sustituye la 'i' por su valor dentro de la condicion, estoy googleando a ver si encuentro la manera de hacerlo pero de momento solo he encontrado la forma de interpretar esa 'i' en un comando echo.

Comment: He editado, simular arrays en Batch es un poco engorroso. Por suerte hay una buena [respuesta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: Tras ejecutar "setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion" ya funciona esa sintaxis tal cual, he conseguido ejecutar la entrada en un bucle while simulado como sugerias, muchas gracias por tu ayuda Pablo.

Comment: En ese caso te agradecería que marcase la respuesta como "aceptada" para que la pregunta quede como respondida

Comment: Si, le he dado pero me dice que al ser nuevo que se queda registrada mi propuesta pero no se modifica, supongo que lo tendran que revisar los admins y aceptar la sugerencia de respuesta valida.

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo votar con seleccionar como respuesta aceptada